# Missing required whitespace from connection string in Web.config

Tags: asp.net, .net, web-config, connection-string, whitespace

My connection string looks like the following:

```
<add name="RaiseFantasyLeagueConnectionString" connectionString="Server=ATLAS-SQL-07;Database=Raise;MultipleActiveResultSets="True" User Id=***; Password=*******/>
```

I am getting an error on `MultipleActiveResultSets="True"` saying

> Missing Required Whitespace.

Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The highlighting here on SO tells you the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This connection string has multiple problems.

- The True value in `MultipleActiveResultSets=True` should not be quoted
- There should be a semicolon after `MultipleActiveResultSets=True`
- There should be a closing quote after the password.

Try it like this:

```
<add name="RaiseFantasyLeagueConnectionString" connectionString="Server=ATLAS-SQL-07;Database=Raise;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;User Id=***;Password=*******"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put a semicolon

```
MultipleActiveResultSets="True"; User Id=
                               ^
                               |
```